# Apply array to "new" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming

I want to write a function like this:

```
function myNew(constructor) {
    return constructor.applyNew(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
}
```

Only `applyNew` doesn't exist. Is there a way around this?

Comment: What is `applyNew`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @putvande A hypothetical combination of `new` +  `Function.prototype.apply`

Comment: @PatrickEvans How? It should have `new` semantics *and* perform application is in `apply`.

Comment: Consider defining the "`applyNew`" semantics better - in case they aren't what I'm championing ;-) - and removing the `myNew` context which doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: So is this right: you want to call some function using `new` but send in a variable number of arguments? It is hard to tell because of the way you use `arguments` in your example.

Answer (score 3):

You first have to create an object that inherits from the constructor function's prototype, and then apply the constructor function to that object to initialize it:

```
function applyNew(fn, args) {
    var obj;
    obj = Object.create(fn.prototype);
    fn.apply(obj, args);
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Definitely seems like a legit way to do it in ES5+ (the linked/duplicate question has a number of ES3 answers).

Comment: +1 Wouldn't it be handy to have an operator so you could just do `foo fn(args)`. Oh wait, there is one. It's called *new*. :-)

Comment: @RobG, assuming the constructor is set up to accept an array instead of a series of arguments, which is not always possible. Generally speaking, `new` should be preferred when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Edited (I didn't think about the array before):

```
function myNew(constructor) {
    var args = arguments;
    function F() {
        return constructor.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1));
    }
    F.prototype = constructor.prototype;
    return new F();
}
```

Comment: That would pass an *array* into the constructor parameters.

Comment: however, that won't allow the constructor to be called with a dynamic number of arguments, it assumes that the constructor accepts an array.

Comment: Correct, I didn't think about that. I edited my answer.

Comment: Those are the wrong `arguments`

Comment: Correct, missed it again ...

Comment: I like this, and unlike the other answer it works for `myNew(Error, 'message')`, but `myNew(Date)` is still a problem. If only builtins are problems like that they could be made special cases.